# How can I check the validity of a selfsigned xrdp certificate

Tags: openssl, rdp, pem

I am connecting to a fedora xrdp server from the built-in Windows Remote Desktop client.

I have access to the `/etc/xrdp/key.pem` and to the certificate inspection window on on Windows Remote Desktop

[image]

In this case I am connecting to a local IP, but is there a way to check if I am connecting to the expected server?

I have already tried using computing the thumbprint "manually"

`sudo grep -v ^- /etc/xrdp/key.pem  | base64 -d | sha256sum`

and also using `openssl`

`sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/xrdp/key.pem -text`

The first one provides an hash that does not match any hashes in the certificate inspection window and the second one give the error

```
unable to load certificate
140669422693888:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: The openssl error suggests that it's not a PEM, but DER-encoded certificate

Comment: Try this command "openssl.exe x509 -in <certificate> -noout -inform DER -startdate -enddate"

Comment: I tried the command `sudo openssl  x509 -in /etc/xrdp/key.pem -noout -inform DER -text` but this gives the error 

`unable to load certificate
140411762589184:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140411762589184:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509`